# PHP - Transposing data

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to achieve the following result:

[image]

Basically what I am able to do, currently, is output a CSV file with transposed data as shown on the left portion of image above. My issue is trying to get the columns names which have also been transposed and be on the same line as the resulting queried data (what I want to achieve is demonstrated on the right side of the above image).

My code is as follows:

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$headers = array();    
$rows = array();
$row_names = array();

while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    if(empty($headers)) {
        $headers = array_keys($result);

        // Transpose column names
        foreach($headers as $key=>$val)
        {
            $row_names[$key][] = $val;
        }
    }

    // Transpose column data
    foreach($result as $key=>$val)
    {
        $rows[$key][] = $val;
    }
}

// Prints the row names
foreach($row_names as $name)
{
   fputcsv ($output, $name); 
}

// Prints the row data
foreach($rows as $row)
{
   fputcsv ($output, $row); 
}


fclose($output);

exit;
```

I know I probably have to somehow combine the $rows with $row_names and then do a single foreach with an fputcsv but I'm not sure how to accomplish this...

Here's the output from $result:

```
Array
(
[Tail #] => N6232D
[Aircraft Configuration] => IR
[Flight Date] => 2015-11-05
[Pilot (Last Name)] => Mars
[Airport] => GA03
[City] => Ringgold
[State/Province] => GA
[Pre-Hobbs Time] => 41242
[Post-Hobbs Time] => 23423
[Hobbs Time] => -17819
[Pre-Tach Time] => 
[Post-Tach Time] => 
[Tach Time] => 
[Window Start Time] => 00:00:00
[Window Close Time] => 00:00:00
[Total Image Window] => 00:00:00
[On Station (Revenue)] => 00:00:00
[Weather] => 00:00:00
[ATC] => 00:00:00
[Pictometry Equip Failure/Delay] => 00:00:00
[Unscheduled Maintenance Time] => 00:00:00
[Scheduled Maintenance Time] => 00:00:00
[Pilot Delay] => 00:00:00
[Ground Support Delay] => 00:00:00
[Ferry] => 01:00:00
[Fueling/Lunch] => 00:00:00
[Plane - No Pilot] => 00:00:00
[Nothing Assigned] => 00:00:00
[Other/Miscellaneous] => 02:15:00
[Pilot Reported Times] => 03:15:00
[Completed Flight Plans (Include Project Name)] => 
[Partial Flight Plans] => 
[Date of Last Control Field] => 2015-10-05
[Drives Shipped Tracking Number] => 
[Spare Drive Sets] => -1
[Remarks] => 
[Status] => APPROVED
)
```

Here's a snippet of the output from $row_names:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Tail #
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Aircraft Configuration
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Flight Date
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Pilot (Last Name)
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Airport
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => City
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => State/Province
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => Pre-Hobbs Time
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => Post-Hobbs Time
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => Hobbs Time
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => Pre-Tach Time
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => Post-Tach Time
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => Tach Time
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => Window Start Time
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => Window Close Time
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => Total Image Window
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => On Station (Revenue)
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [0] => Weather
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [0] => ATC
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [0] => Pictometry Equip Failure/Delay
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [0] => Unscheduled Maintenance Time
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [0] => Scheduled Maintenance Time
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [0] => Pilot Delay
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [0] => Ground Support Delay
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [0] => Ferry
    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [0] => Fueling/Lunch
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [0] => Plane - No Pilot
    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [0] => Nothing Assigned
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [0] => Other/Miscellaneous
    )

[29] => Array
    (
        [0] => Pilot Reported Times
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [0] => Completed Flight Plans (Include Project Name)
    )

[31] => Array
    (
        [0] => Partial Flight Plans
    )

[32] => Array
    (
        [0] => Date of Last Control Field
    )

[33] => Array
    (
        [0] => Drives Shipped Tracking Number
    )

[34] => Array
    (
        [0] => Spare Drive Sets
    )

[35] => Array
    (
        [0] => Remarks
    )

[36] => Array
    (
        [0] => Status
    )
```

Here's a snippet of the output from $rows:

```
Array
(
[Tail #] => Array
    (
        [0] => N6232D
        [1] => N6232D
        [2] => N6232D
        [3] => N6232D
        [4] => N6232D
    )

[Aircraft Configuration] => Array
    (
        [0] => IR
        [1] => IR
        [2] => IR
        [3] => IR
        [4] => IR
    )

[Flight Date] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-11-01
        [1] => 2015-11-05
        [2] => 2015-11-06
        [3] => 2015-11-08
        [4] => 2015-11-09
    )

[Pilot (Last Name)] => Array
    (
        [0] => Mars
        [1] => Mars
        [2] => Mars
        [3] => Mars
        [4] => Mars
    )

[Airport] => Array
    (
        [0] => KROC
        [1] => GA03
        [2] => C37
        [3] => GA03
        [4] => PHNL
    )

[City] => Array
    (
        [0] => Rochester
        [1] => Ringgold
        [2] => Brodhead
        [3] => Ringgold
        [4] => Honolulu
    )

[State/Province] => Array
    (
        [0] => NY
        [1] => GA
        [2] => WI
        [3] => GA
        [4] => HI
    )

[Pre-Hobbs Time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12500
        [1] => 41242
        [2] => 15666.8
        [3] => 15690
        [4] => 15000
    )

[Post-Hobbs Time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12501.9
        [1] => 23423
        [2] => 15669.8
        [3] => 15699.5
        [4] => 15000.9
    )

[Hobbs Time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1.89999999999964
        [1] => -17819
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 9.5
        [4] => 0.899999999999636
    )

[Pre-Tach Time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
    )

[Post-Tach Time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
    )

[Tach Time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
    )

[Window Start Time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12:35:00
        [1] => 00:00:00
        [2] => 15:30:00
        [3] => 15:30:00
        [4] => 12:30:00
    )

[Window Close Time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15:40:00
        [1] => 00:00:00
        [2] => 17:15:00
        [3] => 17:15:00
        [4] => 15:45:00
    )

[Total Image Window] => Array
    (
        [0] => 03:05:00
        [1] => 00:00:00
        [2] => 01:45:00
        [3] => 01:45:00
        [4] => 03:15:00
    )

[On Station (Revenue)] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 00:00:00
        [2] => 00:50:00
        [3] => 00:00:00
        [4] => 00:00:00
    )
```

Comment: Instead of an image, it would help if you include actual text output showing a few rows of `print_r($result)` so we can see exactly what your query returns. Then also include a plain text table of what the intended output should be. It is too difficult to understand the image, particularly because it is shown in context of spreadsheet cells.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for responding. I updated my question appropriately including the data captured in $result as well as a more detail image of what the CSV file should like when generated.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a simple `for` loop with an index counter, provided that both arrays are the same size. And use `array_merge` to merge both the header name and the values in one row.

```
// Prints the row names and the values in one row.
$count_rows = count($rows);
for($i=0; $i<$count_rows; $i++)
{
   fputcsv ($output, array_merge($row_names[$i], $rows[$i])); 
}
```

** edit **

Given the new information you can change the beginning of the code like this

```
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    if(empty($headers)) {
        $headers = array_keys($result);

        // Transpose column names
        foreach($headers as $key=>$val)
        {
            $rows[$key][] = $val;
        }
    }

    // Transpose column data
    foreach($result as $key=>$val)
    {
        $rows[$key][] = $val;
    }
}
```

Note that both the header names and the values are now stored in the same array, but because the header always comes first it always becomes the first value of each row which is what you want.

Now we can just use one `foreach` on the rows.

```
// Prints the row data
foreach($rows as $row)
{
   fputcsv ($output, $row); 
}
```

Comment: In the image that is the case, but I leave it to StephanJW to tell me that ;)

Comment: I was trying to harness array_merge but the arrays are not the same size. Basically $row_names consists of the column names taken from the PostgreSQL query. Where $rows represents the data that is found underneath each of those columns.

Comment: I've added some more information to the question which may help bring some clarity.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the same output as before. But it looks like I found a solution... see me edited response. Appreciate you taking the time to assist me!

Answer (score 0):

It appears I needed to offset the $rows array each time I transpose:

```
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    if(empty($headers)) {
        $headers = array_keys($result);

        // Transpose column names
        foreach($headers as $key=>$val)
        {
            $rows[$key][] = $val;
        }

    }

    // Offset for data (by one column)
    $i = 0;

    // Transpose column data
    foreach($result as $key=>$val)
    {
        $rows[$key+$i][] = $val;
        $i++;
    }
}

// Prints the row data
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
```